# Input-event seems not to be available on a vuetify checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, vue.js, input, vuetify.js

I want to invoke a method when the user selects one of the checkboxes I am rendering via `v-for`. They are all bound to one variable via `v-model`. The problem is that the `input` does not seem to be available on `v-checkbox`. And the following code does not do anything:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-layout row>
                <v-flex xs12>
                <v-layout justify-center>
                    <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation>
                        <v-checkbox
                        v-for="(answer, index) in questions[actualIndex].answers"
                        :key="index"
                        :ref="'check'+index"
                        :label="answer.answer"
                        :value="answer.answer"
                        v-model="checkbox"
                        @input="onInput()"
                        ></v-checkbox>
                    </v-form>
                </v-layout>
            </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template
```

> ```
> export default {
> data() {
>     return {
>     checkbox: ''
>         }
>     },
> methods: {
> onInput() {
>         console.log("WORKS");
>
>     }
>
>   }
> }
> ```

However, if I use the `@change` or `@click` events instead, it works perfectly.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `@change` detects any input changes, so you could use that. `@input` is no native event of a `v-checkbox`, so it won't work: See the tab "EVENTS" https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls#api

Comment: Just out of curiosity; Why are you binding all inputs to one key `checkbox`?

Comment: I need just one value which has been selected. I'm trying to implement a radio-button functionality with checkboxes.

Comment: @BennettDams I think your comment is an appropriate Answer.

Comment: @BennettDams Just a note: `events` tab corresponds to the selected component. When you check v-checkbox, there is no events tab, so seems like the docs is not completed.

Comment: @Traxo yeah, exactly!

Answer (score 2):

`v-model` for `VCheckbox` is bound to the `input-value` prop and the `change` event, so it won't react to the `input` event.
It's not really obvious from the spec, I had to read the [source code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/selectable/index.ts#L19) to understand it.

Here's what I do when I need to do something more complex than simply update a variable.

```html
    <v-checkbox
        :input-value="some expression"
        @change="doWhatever($event)"
    ></v-checkbox>
```

If what you need is to update a variable and get a callback, then `v-model` and `@change` is the way to go.